# Rails 3: Detect if cookies are disabled on server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

Whats the best way to do this (if possible at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article http://clearcove.ca/2009/09/rails-cookie-detection/.
I think it got it all covered, and it has some source code too.